# My symmetry is off but only on the lower jaw of my model?

Tags: modeling

I am making a Chimpanzee skull and everything was fine until a few moments ago when I started to work on the lower jaw, I realized that the symmetry was off even though I didn't mess with it. [image]

Does someone know how I could fix it?

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, it looks like the lower jaw is a separate object (correct?) and that the origin of that object has been accidentally moved somehow. In Object Mode, select the jaw, right click, and go to "Set Origin". You should see a few options; select "Origin to Center of Mass (Surface)". That should get your origin back to the right place and fix the symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

After checking if the origin of the object is in the correct site (which should be where you want the center of the mesh, typically the world origin when sculpting), you can go to edit mode, mesh menu, and choose symmetrize. In the bottom left black panel you can choose axis and direction of the symmetry.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(I am the person who originally posted the question but had to make an account, as I was unregistered when asking the original question)
I am replying to @josh sanfelici, this is what happens when I go into edit mode and then select mesh, then symmetry.
[image]

This happens on the jaw, (I did ctrl z it since I don't think that was supposed to happen).
I did see earlier that there was an orange little dot and it didn't seem to be in the center of the jaw. I don't know how it moved or how I can even put it back.

[image]

Comment: Select in edit mode one vertex which is exactly (or nearly) at the center of the jaw, then press Shift S (cursor to selected); then in object mode with the jaw selected right click and choose set origin (origin to 3D cursor), then try to use the symmetrize function. Shift C to put the 3D cursor in the world center again.

Answer (score 0):

Replying to josh, 
I think I did everything that you said to the best of my ability but now there seems to be another problem. (probably something I did wrong).
[image]

There now seems to be a point next to the jaw if you look to the right.
I can click on it but don't know what it is.
Is there anyway I might be able to send you the file and you could look at it?

[image]

Comment: If you apply the remesh modifier you may be able to get rid of any floating geo that may be giving you problems, recenter the objects origin point to the center of the mesh then continue sculpting.